# Linux external drive not recognized on new computer

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I created an external linux usb drive to use in conjunction with my windows machine. My windows machine died overnight. I moved my usb drive to a new computer however when I check bios boot order my drive does not show up. Any ideas on how to boot into this drive?

Comment: Default install of grub2 boot loader is to first drive. So did boot loader get installed to your now dead system? And you do not have boot files/partition on USB drive? Is install UEFI or BIOS on USB  drive? Or is it just that you need to select correct boot option in one time boot key on new system?

Comment: Alternatively: Boot from a different drive (USB, HD, whatever), then make your external USB drive bootable.